# Is this pattern valid for communicating among multiple firestore databases?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently brainstorming and wondering if it's possible to easily communicate among multiple firestore databases. If so, I could isolate collections and therefore also isolate writes/updates on those collections from competing with other services reducing the risk that I hit the 10,000 write limit p/second on a given database.

Conceptually, I figure I can capture the necessary information from one document in DB_A (including the doc_id) in a read and then set that document in DB_B with the matching doc_id.

In a working example, perhaps one page has a lot of content (documents) that I need to generate and I don't want those writes to compete with writes used in other services on my app. When a user visits this page, we show those documents from DB_A and if the user is interested in one of those documents, we can take that document that we've effectively already read, and now write it into DB_B where user-specific content lives. It seems practical enough. Are there any indexing problems / other problems that could come out of this solution that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you give the databases themselves are not communicating, but your app is communicating with multiple database instances. That is indeed possible. Since you can only have one Firestore instance per project, you will need to [add multiple projects to your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects).

What you're describing is known as sharding, as each database becomes a shard of (a subset of) your entire data set.

Note that it is quite uncommon to have shards to Firestore. If you predict such a high volume of writes, also have a look at Firebase's Realtime Database - as that is typically better suited for use-cases with more, small writes. Firestore is more suited for use-cases that have fewer larger writes, and many more readers. While you may also still to shard (and possibly shard more to reach the same read capacity) with Realtime Database, it can have multiple database instances per project - making the process easier to manage.

Comment: Ah good point, you're completely right about that wording. Also, thanks for the detailed answer, I figured that was sharding but I've only been exposed to that in relation to SQL databases and wasn't sure if this example fell under that umbrella. To add to your comment I found a great link here that generally details the optimal database for needs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore